# Do random variables bounded by random variables which converge in mean also converge in mean?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_n \ge 0$ be a sequence of random variables such that $X_n \to X$ in distribution.

Assume that $X_n$ is [stochastically dominated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance) by $Y_n \ge 0$, $Y_n \to Y$ in distribution, and $\mathbb{E}[Y_n] \to \mathbb{E}[Y]$.

Then do we have $\mathbb{E} X_n \to \mathbb{E}(X)$?

---

My guess is yes.

$Y_n$ is uniformly integrable. This is because we can find a coupling $(Y_n, Y_n')$ such that $Y_n' \sim Y_n$ and $Y_n' \to Y_n$ in probability. Since $\mathbb{E}(Y_n')=\mathbb{E}(Y_n) \to \mathbb{E}[Y]$, $Y_n'$ is uniformly integrable. This in turn suggests $Y_n$ is uniformly integrable.

This implies that $X_n$ is uniformly integrable. So we have $\mathbb{E}{X_n} \to \mathbb{E}{X}$. Is this correct?

Can we omit the condition that $Y_n \to Y$ in distribution?

Comment: What do u mean by "stochastic dominance"?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I added a bit more explanation of my thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you drop the assumption that $Y_n \to Y$ in distribution then  $Y$ almost looses its relevance. On $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure take $X_n=nI_{(0,\frac 1 n)},Y_n=X_n, X=0$ and  $Y=1$. This will give you a counterexample.

Comment: But is my argument correct when $Y_n \to Y$ in distribution?

Comment: @ablmf I think your argument is correct when you have convergence in distribution.